# Screen lock types None and Swipe is disabled

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, lock-screens, lenovo-a6000-plus

When I tried to remove my screen lock, the screen lock types None and Swipe is disabled. It shows that "disabled by administrator, encryption policy , or credential storage". How can I change my screen lock to None ?

Comment: Is your device disk encrypted?

Comment: How can I check it?

Comment: Usually this means that you have installed a user certificate in the security section. Once you did that you can no longer "None" or "Swipe", you have to first execute "Remove all certificates" function in the security settings of Android.

Comment: I removed all the certificates and None and Swipe are enabled now. Thanks